# RequiresPermission annotations with "allOf" in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin, I'd like to add a method annotation that's equivalent to this `RequiresPermission` annotation in Java, indicating that multiple permissions are required:

```
@RequiresPermission(allOf = {ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION})
public Location getLocation() {
    // ...
}
```

How can I write this annotation in Kotlin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass in an array of items as an annotation parameter with `arrayOf`:

```
@RequiresPermission(allOf = arrayOf(ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
fun getLocation(): Location {
    // ...
}
```

You can actually get to this solution by just pasting your Java code into a Kotlin file Android Studio as well.

Update: [since Kotlin 1.2](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#array-literals-in-annotations), you can use an [array literal syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#arrays-as-annotation-parameters) as well:

```
@RequiresPermission(allOf = [ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION])
fun getLocation(): Location {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Android studio suggests to use `@RequiresPermission(allOf = [ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION])`,
but then compiler error is shown. Do you now what is going on?

Comment: That's a new feature introduced in Kotlin 1.2, see here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#array-literals-in-annotations